# Json.NET Uri (de)serialization errors

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net, deserialization

I need to serialize and deserialize an object that contains an System.Uri property using the latest (4.0.3) [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) library.

The following code demonstrates the problem:

```
string input = "http://test.com/%22foo+bar%22";
Uri uri = new Uri(input);
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(uri);
Uri output = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Uri>(json);
```

The DeserializeObject method throws an JsonReaderException. This works fine with 4.0.2.

I've submitted an issue on codeplex with tests and patch to fix the issue, but it seems it takes a bit for the author to release a fixed version.

Meanwhile is there anything i can do ( using JsonSettings or anything else ) to make the latest version work as expected?

A few options i have so far:

1. stick to 4.0.2 - new nuget packages depend on 4.0.3
2. change uri to string - i rather go with option 1 and manually managed pkg dependencies
3. use custom build with patch applied - this is what i'm doing now but i hate the idea of overriding the nuget package's assemblies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write a helper class that circumvents the usual handling of `System.Uri` and treats it purely as a string, using the `Uri.OriginalString` property.

Here's a code sample that does exactly that with a converter class derived from Json.Net's `JsonConverter`.

[OriginalString Property (System.Uri) @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.originalstring.aspx)

One caveat is that you must update all places where you use JsonConvert to include the helper class as one of the extra `JsonConverter` parameters.

I've also added an example using Uri as a member variable in a class, to demonstrate that one wouldn't necessarily have to override the attributes on a class, though it might be more convenient for you. If so, you could use `[JsonConverter(UriConverter)]` as an attribute on members that need it.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace JsonUriSerializeTest
{
    class Program
    {
        public class UriConverter : JsonConverter
        {
            public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
            {
                return objectType.Equals(typeof(Uri));
            }

            public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
            {
                if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.String)
                {
                    return new Uri((string)reader.Value);
                }

                if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
                {
                    return null;
                }

                throw new InvalidOperationException("Unhandled case for UriConverter. Check to see if this converter has been applied to the wrong serialization type.");
            }

            public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
            {
                if (null == value)
                {
                    writer.WriteNull();
                    return;
                }

                if (value is Uri)
                {
                    writer.WriteValue(((Uri)value).OriginalString);
                    return;
                }

                throw new InvalidOperationException("Unhandled case for UriConverter. Check to see if this converter has been applied to the wrong serialization type.");
            }
        }

        public class UriPair
        {
            public string label { get; set; }
            public Uri first { get; set; }
            public Uri second { get; set; }

            public void Display()
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("label:  {0}", label));
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("first:  {0}", first));
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("second: {0}", second));
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = "http://test.com/%22foo+bar%22";
            Uri uri = new Uri(input);
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(uri, new UriConverter());
            Uri output = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Uri>(json, new UriConverter());

            Console.WriteLine(input);
            Console.WriteLine(output.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine();

            UriPair pair = new UriPair();
            pair.label = input;
            pair.first = null;
            pair.second = new Uri(input);
            string jsonPair = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pair, new UriConverter());
            UriPair outputPair = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UriPair>(jsonPair, new UriConverter());

            outputPair.Display();
            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The author of Json.NET fixed the issue, unfortunately the fix will only be in the next version. Till then, if i can i'll stick to 4.0.2 if not use 4.0.3 with a custom Converter