# Proper Json.net System.Object Round-trip?

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

Using the Newtonsoft.Json library, imagine I have got

```
public class Test
{
   public Object Obj { get; set; }
}
```

Now, attempting to serialize this like so

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Test(){ Obj = new Uri(@"http://www.google.com") });
```

...will give me the following JSON

```
{
    "Obj": "http://www.google.com"
}
```

Which is clearly not enough information to deserialize this back into a Uri object, and in fact, attempting to deserialize it will give me a String object instead.

Is there any existing way to correctly serialize and deserialize the type information here so that the object will be read back in as a Uri instead of a String? In this particular case, I am only attempting to interop with a .NET application and it is extremely important that the exact types are deserialized.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to convert the string back to the Uri, you can use custom converter attribute

The converter

```
public class UriConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.String)
        {
            //try to create uri out of the string
            Uri uri;
            if(Uri.TryCreate(reader.Value.ToString(), UriKind.Absolute, out uri))
            {
                return uri;
            }
            //just a string -> return string value
            return reader.Value;
        }

        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        throw new InvalidOperationException("Unable to process JSON");
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (null == value)
        {
            writer.WriteNull();
            return;
        }

        if (value is Uri)
        {
            writer.WriteValue(((Uri)value).OriginalString);
            return;
        }

        throw new InvalidOperationException("Unable to process JSON");
    }
}
```

And the use attribute

```
 [JsonConverter(typeof(UriConverter))]
 public object Obj {get;set;}
```

You should then be able to determine whether the underlying object is Uri like

```
  var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourObject>(yourJSONString);
  if (data.Obj is Uri)
  {
       ... add logic here
  }
  else
  {
       ... not Uri different logic
  }
```

You can also check out this article for more information [Json.NET Uri (de)serialization errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792382/json-net-uri-deserialization-errors)

Comment: Thank you. This would indeed solve the issue if the System.Object was known to always be a Uri, but unfortunately it's not (and otherwise I would just change the type in the class declaration).

Comment: +1 Awesome, I've used JSON.NET for years and didn't know it was anything like this sophisticated!

Comment: You should be able to rewrite the converter to work with your scenario, identifying whether the string is Uri and return it as Uri accordingly. I will rewrite the converter for your scenario

Comment: I also wonder if this solution would suffice if Uri's were nested inside of Obj (i.e. Obj isn't a Uri object, but for example, an Object[] that also held a Uri...).

I admit that I'm peeved that Json.net will uncontrollably force all of my Uri objects to strings...

Comment: It is generally a bad idea to deserialise into object types. Normally a property should only expect a single type. Does the latest update fit your scenario?

Answer (score 1):

JSON only knows about the JavaScript data types: string, number and boolean.  An URL is not in the list.

In fact, the entire POINT of JSON is to allow a loosely typed transfer.  If you want strongly typed transfer, check out a stronger transfer protocol, like WCF binary serialization.

Comment: While I agree with you in general with regards to the intention of JSON to allow loosely typed transfer, Json.net has flexibility with regards to .NET types (through the special $type property and the TypeNameHandling settings). It just happens that it special cases a Uri to a String...

In any case, thank you, I will consider WCF binary serialization.