# Can not customize serializer with RavenDB and JsonConverter - possible incompatability with Json.Net 4.0.8

Tags: json.net, ravendb, restsharp

For my project I must deserialize a Uri string, and am following the suggestion offered in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792382/json-net-uri-deserialization-errors) by creating a custom converter.

When I add the convert to the serializer exposed in RavenDB I get the following error:

*TestSuite.EmailSMSTests.CanSendSMSWithFilter:
System.ArrayTypeMismatchException : Attempted to access an element as a type incompatible with the array.*

I am adding the converter in this fashion:

```
docStore.Conventions.CustomizeJsonSerializer = serializer => serializer.Converters.Add(new UriJsonConverter());
docStore.Initialize();
```

I can successfully add the converter if I create a JsonSerializer with Json.Net:

```
var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
serializer.Converters.Add(new UriJsonConverter());
```

I suspect that this may be due to an assembly redirect, since I need a later version of Json.Net that works with RESTSharp.  The project uses Raven.client 960, Json.Net 4.08 and Json.Net 4.5.7.  Any insight is welcomed.

This is the code for the converter:

```
public class UriJsonConverter : JsonConverter
    {

        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return object.Equals(objectType, typeof(Uri));
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            switch (reader.TokenType)
            {
                case JsonToken.String:
                    return CreateUri((string)reader.Value);
                case JsonToken.Null:
                    return null;
                default:
                    var msg = string.Format("Unable to deserialize Uri from token type {0}", reader.TokenType);
                    throw new InvalidOperationException(msg);
            }
        }

        private static Uri CreateUri(string uriString)
        {
            Uri uri;
            if (!Uri.TryCreate(uriString, UriKind.Absolute, out uri))
                if (!Uri.TryCreate(uriString, UriKind.Absolute, out uri))
                    if (!Uri.TryCreate(uriString, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, out uri))
                    {
                        var msg = string.Format("Unable to determine proper UriKind for Uri {0}", uriString);
                        throw new InvalidOperationException(msg);
                    }
            return uri;
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            if (null == value)
            {
                writer.WriteNull();
                return;
            }

            var uri = value as Uri;
            if (uri != null)
            {
                writer.WriteValue(uri.OriginalString);
                return;
            }
            var msg = string.Format("Unable to serialize {0} with {1}", value.GetType(), typeof(UriJsonConverter));
            throw new InvalidOperationException(msg);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Raven client 972 that uses json 4.5.7?
https://nuget.org/packages/RavenDB.Client/1.0.972

Comment: yes, I did.  But because I am using the Authorization bundle as well I have to remain with 960.

Answer (score 0):

Raven DB, for some strange reason, includes an old version of Newtonsoft JSON in their client. To register a type converter, you have to do something like this:

```
using (var store = new DocumentStore { Url = "http://..." })
{
    store.Initialize();

    // Required if you are going to serialize Identity types
    store.Conventions.IdentityTypeConvertors.Add(new IdentityTypeConverter());

    // This is how you register 
    store.Conventions.CustomizeJsonSerializer = serializer => serializer.Converters.Add(new IdentityTypeConverter());

...
}
```